# Excel Vba - Dynamic Filter Range Delete

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code block to take out various errors and assign an error code description to the data.  It works fine as long as the filter returns a result.  If it does not then it deletes the header row.  How can I prevent that from happening? Thanks in advance.

```
Sheets("Tempsheet").Select
Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter
Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0", Criteria2:=0
Range("K2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "Excluded: $0.00 Amount"
Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Excluded").Select
Range("A2").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Tempsheet").Select
Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete
Sheets("Tempsheet").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, exactly what I needed!

Comment: No problem. Its worth noting that the SpecialCells approach will work regardless of your data layout (ie if it began in row 2 or row 10 rather than row 1), so it offers flexibility beyond your current layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no data is returned by the filter then `Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` will return row 1, so test for `row > 1` before doing the Delete

```
If Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Row > 1 then
    ... .Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this code which tests for a filter result should do it

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Tempsheet")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Excluded")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "k").End(xlUp))
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0", Criteria2:=0
If rng1.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
    ws.Range("K2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "Excluded: $0.00 Amount"
    ws.Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Copy
    ws2.[a2].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Sheets("Tempsheet").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Tempsheet").Select
Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter
Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0", Criteria2:=0
Range("K2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "Excluded: $0.00 Amount"
Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Excluded").Select
Range("A2").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Tempsheet").Select

if Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 then
  Range("A2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete
end if

Sheets("Tempsheet").AutoFilterMode = False
```